using determinants to represent lines and circles that join 2 and 3 points
let A(A.x,A.y), B(B.x,B.y) and C(C.x,C.y) be some 3 points (ill use the .x and .y to represent the x,y coordinates of the points)
to start off, the line joining 2 points can be shown by equaling the gradient of 1 point to any point of the line, and the gradient between the 2 known points
$$\frac{y-A.y}{x-A.x} = \frac{A.y-B.y}{A.x-B.x}$$
but for some reason, the same line can be represented using a determinant equaled to 0
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x & y & 1 \\
A.x & A.y & 1 \\
B.x & B.x & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} =0
$$
this can be extended to a circle that passes through 3 points too as,
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x^2+y^2 & x & & y & 1 \\
A.x^2+A.y^2 & A.x & & A.y & 1 \\
B.x^2+B.y^2 & B.x & & B.y & 1 \\
C.x^2+C.y^2 & C.x & & A.y & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} =0
$$
my question is, why does this work? i`ve not done linear algebra or such advanced topics yet, could someone explain why this works, and how to use this further?

For the circle, see the older Q&A here. The idea, as outlined in Piquito's answer, works for the line as well: the first row effectively encodes the equation of a given curve (as a linear function of its parameters), and the remaining rows encode the points required to uniquely specify a particular curve.

This is related to Conformal Geometric Algebra through the relationship between geometric algebra, exterior algebra, and determinants. This idea works for arbitrary $n$-spheres.

Also notice that your first determinant can be written $$\begin{vmatrix}x^2+y^2&x&y&1\1&0&0&0\A_x^2+A_y^2&A_x&A_y&1\B_x^2+B_y^2&B_x&B_y&1\end{vmatrix}.$$ (I've use subscripts instead of your dots.) This looks just like your circle-from-three-points determinant, and this is no accident: $(1,0,0,0)$ represents the point at infinity, and a line is just a circle passing through the point at infinity and two other points.
